# ZooKeeper max number of children per node

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I am using ZooKeeper to store hierarchical data. In one test I stored more than 300K children for under one node. ZK client crashed due to a ConnectionLossException when I tried to retrieve ALL children.

Remodeling the data might solve the problem (e.g. by bucketing as it reduces the number of children per node).

However I am curious to know the answers of the following questions:

1. ZK has a limitation of data that can stored on one node (no more than 1MB), is there a similar restriction on the number of children per node?
2. Does increasing Java Heap size will allow ZK to scale out the number of children per node?
3. Is there anyway to control the way these children are sent back to client? if the children are sent in one batch then a network "hiccup" could destroy the message and cause failure.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a straight answer for your question, but I do recommend that you give a look at Curator's Tech Notes. For instance, Tech Node #4 contains some information that might help you https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CURATOR/TN4

Comment: The link you provided has very interesting information, the problem presented almost matches my current situation, thanks a lot sharing this.

Answer (score 5):

There's no explicit limit to the number of children.

However, there is a 
limit to the size of the packet that can be sent back from the server in 
response to `getChildren` which effectly ends up being the limit. This is 
controlled with a system property, `jute.maxbuffer` and defaults to 4MB (I 
think you can get a around 200,000 znodes into this, though it also depends 
on the length of the znode name).

Check out [this link](http://zookeeper-user.578899.n2.nabble.com/zookeeper-max-no-of-children-of-znode-td7581228.html) for the full discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Just a day ago, there was an issue on Zookeeper version 3.4.4 where nearly 800K nodes ended up under a single parent node and was causing issues when trying to access that parent node. Tried a few different methods found for deleting a node, of which none of them worked. All hit ConnectionLoss KeeperExceptions.

The `-Djute.maxbuffer` java option when run with a java8 program that uses `ZKUtil.deleteRecursive( zk, path );` via the 3.4.14 java client (not the 3.4.4 java client) worked to delete the 800K children znodes. This jopt did not have to be placed on the server side. It was a *purely* client side change. Did not work with the 3.4.14 zkCli command line client however.

Answer (score 1):

Through the zookeeper source , there's no explicit limit to child count . But the `childCount` is `int` type , the max should is `Integer#MAX_VALUE` .